# Why don't these function definitions work?

Tags: function-construction

picked up Mathematica (transitioning from Python) a couple of days ago so forgive me for the newbie question. I'm trying to create a function which takes in a list of numbers and returns a list of the permutations of the number formed by the concatenation of those numbers. To be more clear ->

foo({1,2,1}) would output {121, 112, 211}. This is how I've tried to implement it.

```
my_function[x_] := FromDigits /@ Permutations[x]
```

Thinking that as long as the user input was a list like `{1,2,3}` this would work just fine. It doesn't seem to, so then I tried

```
my_function[x_,y_,z_] := FromDigits /@ Permutations[{x,y,z}]
```

This also didn't work.

This isn't the first time I've had trouble getting function definitions to work. What is it about my function definitions in this case that is causing them not to work?

Also - I've gone through the fast introduction for Python programmers. Any other recommended newbie resources?

Thanks

Comment: You can't use underscore in identifiers in the way you are used to in python. See [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/81) for details. That Q/A you may find generally useful as well. For resources, I recommend [this QA](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18/where-can-i-find-examples-of-good-mathematica-programming-practice).

Comment: Specifically, change `my_function` to `function` and it will work.

Comment: Thank you to both of you for your answers.